# Performance of group of datetime aggregations Postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

The requirement is to compute a bunch of aggregations on top of each other and end up with JSON. I followed two guidelines: Use group by first then count rather then SELECT (DISTINCT) and I tried to dwindle down the number of involved rows with each consecutive CTE. 
What I end up with is quite a verbose query, not that fast. 
So my question is: Is it worth looking into recursive CTEs under such circumstances? Or any other tip/directions I should look into to reduce query size and/or improve performance?

Prepared statement

```
WITH limited_readings_hours AS (
    SELECT
      "value",
      sensor_id,
      date_trunc('hour', rr.issued) AS issued_hour
    FROM raw_readings rr
    WHERE sensor_id = ANY ($1 :: UUID [])
          AND date_trunc('day', rr.issued) >= date_trunc('day', $2 :: DATE)
          AND date_trunc('day', rr.issued) <= date_trunc('day', $3 :: DATE)
    GROUP BY issued_hour, sensor_id, "value"
),
    hours AS (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)                                                        AS "uniqueVisitors",
        sensor_id                                                       AS "sensorId",
        to_char(issued_hour AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'IYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24"Z"') AS "dateMember"
      FROM limited_readings_hours
      GROUP BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
      ORDER BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
  ),
    limited_readings_days AS (
      SELECT
        "value",
        sensor_id,
        date_trunc('days', issued_hour) AS issued_day
      FROM limited_readings_hours
      GROUP BY issued_day, sensor_id, "value"
  ),
    days AS (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)                                             AS "uniqueVisitors",
        sensor_id                                            AS "sensorId",
        to_char(issued_day AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'IYYY-MM-DD') AS "dateMember"
      FROM limited_readings_days
      GROUP BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
      ORDER BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
  ),
    limited_readings_weeks AS (
      SELECT
        "value",
        sensor_id,
        date_trunc('weeks', issued_day) AS issued_week
      FROM limited_readings_days
      GROUP BY issued_week, sensor_id, "value"
  ),
    weeks AS (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)                                              AS "uniqueVisitors",
        sensor_id                                             AS "sensorId",
        to_char(issued_week AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'IYYY"-W"IW') AS "dateMember"
      FROM limited_readings_weeks
      GROUP BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
      ORDER BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
  ),
    limited_readings_months AS (
      SELECT
        "value",
        sensor_id,
        date_trunc('months', issued_week) AS issued_month
      FROM limited_readings_weeks
      GROUP BY issued_month, sensor_id, "value"),
    months AS (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)                                            AS "uniqueVisitors",
        sensor_id                                           AS "sensorId",
        to_char(issued_month AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'IYYY-MM') AS "dateMember"
      FROM limited_readings_months
      GROUP BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
      ORDER BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
  ),
    limited_readings_years AS (
      SELECT
        "value",
        sensor_id,
        date_trunc('years', issued_month) AS issued_year
      FROM limited_readings_months
      GROUP BY issued_year, sensor_id, "value"),
    years AS (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)                                        AS "uniqueVisitors",
        sensor_id                                       AS "sensorId",
        to_char(issued_year AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'IYYY') AS "dateMember"
      FROM limited_readings_years
      GROUP BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
      ORDER BY "dateMember", "sensorId"
  )

SELECT json_build_object(
           'years', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(years))
                     FROM years),
           'months', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(months))
                      FROM months),
           'weeks', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(weeks))
                     FROM weeks),
           'days', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(days))
                    FROM days),
           'hours', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(hours))
                     FROM hours)
       ) AS "uniqueVisitors";
```

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_readings
(
  raw_reading_id uuid NOT NULL,
  created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  modified timestamp with time zone,
  sensor_id uuid NOT NULL,
  value text,
  issued timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  type text,
  account_id uuid,
  CONSTRAINT raw_readings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (raw_reading_id)
)
```

Analyze output:

```
QUERY PLAN
Result  (cost=8873.92..8873.94 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=713.709..713.710 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE limited_readings_hours
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=8790.07..8791.50 rows=115 width=42) (actual time=642.622..646.458 rows=4432 loops=1)
          Group Key: date_trunc('hour'::text, rr.issued), rr.sensor_id, rr.value
          ->  Seq Scan on raw_readings rr  (cost=0.00..8783.41 rows=888 width=42) (actual time=0.034..441.787 rows=177545 loops=1)
                Filter: ((sensor_id = ANY ('{54993ab8-c0e8-4359-b7c2-77f00a00011a}'::uuid[])) AND (date_trunc('day'::text, issued) >= date_trunc('day'::text, ('2015-01-01'::date)::timestamp with time zone)) AND (date_trunc('day'::text, issued) <= date_trunc('day'::text, ('2015-01-30'::date)::timestamp with time zone)))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 90
  CTE hours
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6.81..9.69 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=29.800..37.062 rows=200 loops=1)
          Group Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_hours.issued_hour), 'IYYY-MM-DDTHH24Z'::text)), limited_readings_hours.sensor_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=6.81..7.10 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=29.751..33.013 rows=4432 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_hours.issued_hour), 'IYYY-MM-DDTHH24Z'::text)), limited_readings_hours.sensor_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 539kB
                ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_hours  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=0.015..8.542 rows=4432 loops=1)
  CTE limited_readings_days
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3.45..4.89 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=660.996..661.571 rows=697 loops=1)
          Group Key: date_trunc('days'::text, limited_readings_hours_1.issued_hour), limited_readings_hours_1.sensor_id, limited_readings_hours_1.value
          ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_hours limited_readings_hours_1  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=642.632..656.110 rows=4432 loops=1)
  CTE days
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6.81..9.69 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=3.260..4.254 rows=9 loops=1)
          Group Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_days.issued_day), 'IYYY-MM-DD'::text)), limited_readings_days.sensor_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=6.81..7.10 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=3.133..3.652 rows=697 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_days.issued_day), 'IYYY-MM-DD'::text)), limited_readings_days.sensor_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 79kB
                ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_days  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=0.014..1.254 rows=697 loops=1)
  CTE limited_readings_weeks
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3.45..4.89 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=663.871..664.138 rows=336 loops=1)
          Group Key: date_trunc('weeks'::text, limited_readings_days_1.issued_day), limited_readings_days_1.sensor_id, limited_readings_days_1.value
          ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_days limited_readings_days_1  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=661.001..663.115 rows=697 loops=1)
  CTE weeks
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6.81..9.69 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=1.545..1.795 rows=2 loops=1)
          Group Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_weeks.issued_week), 'IYYY-WIW'::text)), limited_readings_weeks.sensor_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=6.81..7.10 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=1.246..1.491 rows=336 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_weeks.issued_week), 'IYYY-WIW'::text)), limited_readings_weeks.sensor_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 51kB
                ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_weeks  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=0.012..0.574 rows=336 loops=1)
  CTE limited_readings_months
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3.45..4.89 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=665.277..665.481 rows=248 loops=1)
          Group Key: date_trunc('months'::text, limited_readings_weeks_1.issued_week), limited_readings_weeks_1.sensor_id, limited_readings_weeks_1.value
          ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_weeks limited_readings_weeks_1  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=663.877..664.885 rows=336 loops=1)
  CTE months
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6.81..9.69 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=1.282..1.283 rows=1 loops=1)
          Group Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_months.issued_month), 'IYYY-MM'::text)), limited_readings_months.sensor_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=6.81..7.10 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=0.866..1.048 rows=248 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_months.issued_month), 'IYYY-MM'::text)), limited_readings_months.sensor_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 44kB
                ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_months  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=0.013..0.430 rows=248 loops=1)
  CTE limited_readings_years
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3.45..4.89 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=666.298..666.491 rows=248 loops=1)
          Group Key: date_trunc('years'::text, limited_readings_months_1.issued_month), limited_readings_months_1.sensor_id, limited_readings_months_1.value
          ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_months limited_readings_months_1  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=115 width=56) (actual time=665.287..666.013 rows=248 loops=1)
  CTE years
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6.81..9.69 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=667.923..667.924 rows=1 loops=1)
          Group Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_years.issued_year), 'IYYY'::text)), limited_readings_years.sensor_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=6.81..7.10 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=667.519..667.701 rows=248 loops=1)
                Sort Key: (to_char(timezone('UTC'::text, limited_readings_years.issued_year), 'IYYY'::text)), limited_readings_years.sensor_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 44kB
                ->  CTE Scan on limited_readings_years  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=666.315..667.140 rows=248 loops=1)
  InitPlan 11 (returns $10)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.88..2.89 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=667.986..667.987 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on years  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=667.942..667.944 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 12 (returns $11)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.88..2.89 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=1.325..1.326 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on months  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=1.296..1.298 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 13 (returns $12)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.88..2.89 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=1.849..1.850 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on weeks  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=1.555..1.809 rows=2 loops=1)
  InitPlan 14 (returns $13)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.88..2.89 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=4.340..4.341 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on days  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=3.274..4.288 rows=9 loops=1)
  InitPlan 15 (returns $14)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.88..2.89 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=38.143..38.144 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on hours  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=115 width=24) (actual time=29.805..37.483 rows=200 loops=1)
Execution time: 713.993 ms
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on `raw_readings`?

Comment: Few notes: `issued::date`  could be faster than `date_trunc('day', issued)` and means almost the same; do not use `group by` or `order by` on `to_char(date/timestamp)`, you can use those on the original field/`date_trunc()` if necessary (which also could be faster) and you will get the same results. -- also why do you use `group by` on the results of another `group by`? I'm not sure I get that.

Comment: Yes, using truncate prevented the index usage (combined index of issued and sensor_id).
The second group by is used for the count aggregate. Together it should replace COUNT(DISTINCT value).
Thank you for the help.